# Remove row whose timestamp is in previous sliding window via Pandas in Python

Tags: python, pandas

Here's a problem for cleansing my data. The dataframe looks as below:

```
   timestamp
0  10
1  12
2  23
3  25
4  27
5  34
6  45
```

What I intend to do is iterating through timestamps from top to down, grab one if no previous timestamp is taken (for initialization, It'll take '10'), then omit every row whose timestamp is between [10, 10+10], including '12'. Likewise, we should take '23' and omit '25', '27' since they are between [23, 23+10]. Finally, '34' and '45' should be taken as well.

Eventually, the result would be

```
   timestamp
0  10
2  23
5  34
6  45
```

Could anyone give me some idea to realize this in Pandas? Great thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't believe there is a way to solve this custom problem using a groupby like construct, but here is a coding solution that gives you the index location and timestamp values.

```
stamps = [df.timestamp.iat[0]]
index = [df.index[0]]
for idx, ts in df.timestamp.iteritems():
    if ts >= stamps[-1] + 10:
        index.append(idx)
        stamps.append(ts)

>>> index
[0, 2, 5, 6]

>>> stamps
[10, 23, 34, 45]

>>> df.iloc[index]
   timestamp
0         10
2         23
5         34
6         45
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understood correct about the initialization, but see if this helps you:

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
gap = 10 
actual = 0
for timestamp in df.values:
    if timestamp >= (actual+gap):
        print(timestamp)
        actual = timestamp
```

if you want to create a new DF:

```
df = pd.read_csv("data.csv")
gap = 10 
actual = 0
index = []
for i, timestamp in enumerate(df.values):
    if timestamp >= (actual+gap):
        actual = timestamp
    else:
        index.append(i)

new_df = df.drop(df.index[index])
```

Comment: This is a nice idea, but you should iterate via `iterrows` and (if this is indeed the OP's intention) drop rows along the way as you iterate.